# First digit of a factorial without calculating it

Tags: factorial

I made this small function which use Stirling formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) and the fractional part of log10 to calculate the first digit of a factorial. However I am not sure of its correctness, I know it will likely fail for low number but if we assume n>1000 then I want to know which case it would fail.
Here the gist: https://gist.github.com/hube12/ee3330b6d47a5c87a505a9f81e353b7a

```
def first_digit(n):
    from math import exp,log,pi,modf,sqrt
    w=log((n/exp(1)),10)
    f,i=modf(w*n)
    l=10**f
    p=sqrt(2*pi*n)
    return str(p*l)[0]
```

https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/png/7fe20ccef4b13b2fc2b79b752fb595da6d855de2

Let's take the time to see what I did in math formula:

Stirling (assuming large n) : $ n! \approx \sqrt{2\times\pi \times n} \times (\frac{n}{e})^n $

Now I take the log base 10 of the fraction so $ w= \log_{10}{\frac{n}{e}} $

This allow me then to take the decimal part of $ w \times n $

So I used $ \log_{10}{(\frac{n}{e})^n} = n \times \log_{10}{(\frac{n}{e})} $

Now that I have the decimal part I can raised 10 to that part, $ l= 10^f$ This allow me to get a rational number in [0,10) which represent the highest digit of that power.

Now I only need to multiply that number l by the square root part and get the first digit of that product $ \sqrt{2\times\pi \times n} \times FirstDigit((\frac{n}{e})^n) $

The first digit of that product is the first digit of my factorial, well that's what I am asking if it is correct for every factorial (assuming n>1000 and infinite precision/ correct log)

Cheers,
Neil

Comment: As this is a mathematics site, you may be well advised to state the pertinent mathematical formulas you're using, instead of throwing arbitrary code in arbitrary languages at unsuspecting readers. ;)

Comment: You can ask your question in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) as this problem deals mostly with code than with mathematics

Comment: @ProfessorVector Right! I am still shocked... who on Earth needs the $1$st digit of a factorial???

Comment: The code is clearly in python as of the token def and the indentation suggest, the formula is the stirling formula and the log decomposition, nothing else is used, I need the first digit of a factorial because it's useful in a few edge cases, and it's not much of a code problem (the code is already written) but more one of the mathematical correctness. For instance I do p*l which is the sqrt(n2pi) times 10 to the power of the fractional part of the log10((n/e)^n) which is supposed to give me the first digit of (n/e)^n (which could be incorrect for some cases for instance).

Comment: In that case, it will be helpful if you express your calculation as a mathematical formula instead of as code, so that the mathematicians on this site can better help you verify your formula's correctness.

Comment: @Raffaele Oops, I'm afraid it wasn't a comment of mine you're replying to. The first digit of factorials could be interesting, indeed, as it not necessarily has to follow https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law (I guess it does, though). I was complaining about the absence of mathematical language,and I'd like to think you would agree, especially since it's not the language of Mathematica in that post, either.

Comment: @ProfessorVector It does https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1555271/does-every-finite-digit-sequence-appear-in-some-factorial/1555407#1555407

Answer (score 1):

The formula you need is:
$$\log(N!)=N \log(N) - N \log(e) + \log(2 \pi N)/2 + \log(1+1/(12N)) $$

The below gives me 15 correct digits for $10^9!$:

```
def factorial(N):
    N=Decimal(N)
    p=N*N.log10() - N/Decimal(10).ln() + (2*N*Decimal(math.pi)).log10()/2
    d=int(p)
    p-=d
    return (10**p * (1+1/(12*N)),d)
```

Your formula fails to work since you are using math.e which has insufficient precision. Also, you won't do better than 9 digits unless you add in the second term in the series (1/12N),

Additionally, you don't need str throughout your code, it just makes it messy.